# Matplotlib not plotting full line

Tags: python, matplotlib

As part of my research project, I was working on performing linear regression with some data using matplotlib. Unfortunately, I am unable to get my line to touch the origin; matplotlib seems to cut it off at the minimum value of my dataset. How can I fix this and get my line to touch the origin? As reference, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels import api as sm


def file_analysis(csv_file, state):
    """
    This method takes in a file object and the name of a state.

    :param csv_file: Pass in a csv file object.
    :param state: Name of the state as a string.
    :return: None.
    """
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    data = data[["Total Cases", "Total Deaths"]]

    y = data["Total Deaths"]
    x = data["Total Cases"]

    results = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

    plt.scatter(x, y)
    yhat = results.params[0] * x
    print(results.params)

    plt.ylim(ymin=0)
    plt.xlim(xmin=0)
    plt.margins(0)

    fig = plt.plot(x, yhat, lw=4, c="orange", label="regressionline")

    plt.xlabel("Total Cases", fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('Total Deaths', fontsize=20)
    plt.title(state)

    plt.savefig(state + "_scatterplot" + ".png")
    plt.show()

    with open(state + "_analysis.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(results.summary().as_text())
```

And here is the resulting scatter-plot after passing in the name of the state and the csv file for the state:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just change the x-values that you want in your regression to include 0.

```
yhat = results.params[0] * range(0, x.max())

fig = plt.plot(range(0, x.max()), yhat, lw=4, c="orange", label="regressionline")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That solves it. However, I have a (conceptual) question. Why do we need to assign ```yhat``` to ```results.params[0]*range(0, x.max())```? Why does not just putting ```range(0, x.max())``` for the x value in ```plot()``` solve the issue?

Comment: You are producing an estimate of the OLS model at each value of x provided. So, in order to get an estimate, you have to provide a value of x. If you were to put range(0, x.max()) in the plot without corresponding estimates, then you would have a length problem. That is if you had the plot x-values as [0,2,4,5,7] and the estimates as [4,6,9,10], then there is one extra x-value than y-value, which would trigger an error.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so it is essentially a two-dimensional array that is being built. Nice! Thanks for the help

Comment: Correct! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason your line does not touch the origin is that your are only plotting it at the extent of your data. By calculating the predicted deaths like this `yhat = results.params[0] * x` you are restricting the line to points in your dataset. You can easily fix this if you supply a wider range of x parameters:

```py
newX = range(0, 80)
yhat = results.params[0] * newX
fig = plt.plot(newX, yhat, lw=4, c="orange", label="regressionline")
```

By the way, are you fitting the model without intercept on purpose?

Comment: Yep, I am actually plotting coronavirus cases in nursing homes. Obviously if there are 0 cases, there should be 0 deaths. Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the data, to try the solution I am proposing, but If I was you, I would add a 0 value to the yhat values and also a 0 to the x values in the same position, so you will see the line in the [0,0] position.
Let me know if this works :)

Comment: I was wondering about doing that, but wouldn't this solution screw up the rest of the line by creating bias? I'm sorry, I'm not too well versed in statistics. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: well when you force a regression line to be in the 0,0 point, its the price you pay. Its a true point anyway, think for example that there will be no dead if they are not a case first. Also you are only modifying the regression line, not the data.